# Will insert and update wait while a table is being vacuumed?

Tags: postgresql, locking, postgresql-9.1, vacuum

I want to vacuum a table in PostgreSQL version 9.1 which will take between 10 to 12 minutes.  This needs to be done in real-time, in production use.

I just want to know that if any `INSERT` or `UPDATE` query comes, will they wait for the lock to be lifted, or will they time out?

NOTE: The Java code that will fire the query has not specified any timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html) says the following:

> **ROW EXCLUSIVE**
>
> Conflicts with the SHARE, SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE, EXCLUSIVE, and ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock modes.
>
> The commands **UPDATE**, DELETE, and INSERT acquire this lock mode on the target table (in addition to ACCESS SHARE locks on any other
>   referenced tables). In general, this lock mode will be acquired by any
>   command that modifies data in a table.
>
> **SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE**
>
> Conflicts with the SHARE UPDATE EXCLUSIVE, SHARE, SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE, EXCLUSIVE, and ACCESS EXCLUSIVE lock modes. This mode
>   protects a table against concurrent schema changes and VACUUM runs.
>
> Acquired by **VACUUM** (without FULL), ANALYZE, CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY, and some forms of ALTER TABLE.

There is no conflict between the two lock types involved.  This means that neither `INSERT`/`UPDATE` blocks `VACUUM`, nor the other way around.  This means furthermore that your queries should succeed without timeouts.  Most probably the I/O activity of vacuuming won't do you any harm.

Comment: While this is true, a lower level lock can also back vacuum. [At least the dead row clean up](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/161042/2639)